# heredoc syntax for multi-line perl using stdin from bash

Tags: perl, bash, stdin, heredoc

How to pass file to perl script for processing and also use heredoc syntax for multi-line perl script? I have tried those but no luck:

```
cat ng.input | perl -nae <<EOF
if (@F==2) {print $F[0] . "\t". $F[1] . "\n"} else { print "\t" . $F[0] . "\n" }
EOF

cat ng.input | perl -nae - <<EOF
if (@F==2) {print $F[0] . "\t". $F[1] . "\n"} else { print "\t" . $F[0] . "\n" }
EOF
```

Comment: All you need is `perl -ple'$_="\t$_"if!/\t/'` (if @F!=2 when @F<2, and if the input is specifically tab separated rather than whitespace separated)

Answer (score 3):

There's really no need for here-docs. You could simply use a multi-line argument:

```
perl -nae'
    if (@F==2) {
       print $F[0] . "\t". $F[1] . "\n"
    } else {
       print "\t" . $F[0] . "\n"
    }
' ng.input
```

Clean, more portable than Barmar's, and only uses one process instead of Barmar's three.

---

Note that your code could be shrunk to

```
perl -lane'unshift @F, "" if @F!=2; print "$F[0]\t$F[1]";' ng.input
```

or even

```
perl -pale'unshift @F, "" if @F!=2; $_="$F[0]\t$F[1]";' ng.input
```

Comment: I assume `cat ng.input` in the question is just a placeholder for some other process that will pipe input to the script. Otherwise there wouldn't be a problem using the here-doc.

Comment: @Barmar, That's completely besides the point. A multi-line argument can also be used with `... | perl`. (But to address your comment anyway, you underestimate how many people use `cat file |`.)

Comment: That's why there's a UUOC award, though in actuality, it is hard to find a novel UUOC — they're mainly mundane repetitions of the same old problem, over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Use process substitution:

```
cat ng.input | perl -na <(cat <<'EOF'
if (@F==2) {print $F[0] . "\t". $F[1] . "\n"} else { print "\t" . $F[0] . "\n" }
EOF
)
```

Also put single quotes around the `EOF` tag so that `$F` in the perl script won't be expanded as shell variables.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I didn't even notice the `-e` in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Can also pass a heredoc as a "-" first argument to perl:

```perl
perl -lna - ng.input <<'EOF'
if (@F==2) {print $F[0] . "\t". $F[1] . "\n"} else { print "\t" . $F[0] . "\n" }
EOF
```